# Is this query can be optimized?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have mysql database with a table which has following columns..

```
id
dealerId
month_year
total_price
total_count
vin_prefix
```

and table has 20 million records, i want to get sum(total_price) of all those cars sold by a dealer with ID # 02 (it's pretty simple)

However, i want to get the sum of ALL other dealers who have sold the cars with same vin_prefix as Dealer # 02

So i wrote this query...

```
SELECT d.dealerId 
    FROM `dealer_monthly_report` d 
    where d.dealerId <> 2 
        and d.vin_prefix in (select distinct(d2.vin_prefix) 
                                 from `dealer_monthly_report` d2   
                                 where d2.dealerId = 2) 
    group by d.dealerId
```

But can we optimize this query in anyway ? 
Indexes have been used on dealerId, vin_prefix and month_year seperately.

Thanks !

Comment: Distinct isn't really needed in your IN query. Might be better off without it

Answer (score 1):

Just tried your query and Gordon's query with 1.000.000 records. By adding the index `dealer_monthly_report(vin_prefix, dealerId)` your suggested query seems a bit faster than Gordon's one (about 1-2 seconds for my records).

**Edit: corrected Code for temporary table**

I would suggest to extend the first solution from Gordon as follows:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE vin_prefixes_dealerID_2
    SELECT distinct(d.vin_prefix) as vin_prefix
    FROM `dealer_monthly_report` d
    WHERE d.dealerID = 2
;

SELECT d.dealerId, sum(total_price)
FROM `dealer_monthly_report` d
WHERE d.dealerId <> 2 AND
EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM `vin_prefixes_dealerID_2` d2
    where d.vin_prefix = d2.vin_prefix
)
GROUP BY d.dealerId;
```

This reduced the query time from initial 18-20 seconds to about 6-7 seconds (for 1.000.000 records)

**Edit: Corrected alternative approach**

Alternative approach might be:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE vin_prefixes_dealerID_2
    SELECT distinct(d.vin_prefix) as vin_prefix
    FROM `dealer_monthly_report` d
    WHERE d.dealerID = 2
;

SELECT d.dealerId, sum(d.total_price)
FROM `dealer_monthly_report` d
JOIN `vin_prefixes_dealerID_2` d2
ON d.vin_prefix = d2.vin_prefix
WHERE d.dealerID <> 2
GROUP BY d.dealerId;
```

This reduced the time for processing to about 0.91 (!!!) seconds

Comment: 6-7 seconds for 1 Million records ? i have 22 Million records in table and possibly 50 Million at the end of this year..... Any other option ?

Comment: Well, that was on a macbook (2 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo, 4 GB RAM 1067 MHz DDR3 and a SSD) .. better hardware will definitely improve performance.

Comment: I hardly ever had to deal with that amount of data so I can't really suggest a better way. Either try my second solution (some kind of out of the box) or maybe [Shard Query](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/01/07/increasing-slow-query-performance-with-parallel-query-execution/) helps

Comment: it resulted even slower for my server. unfortunately, i 'm using a VPS which is not a good option.. i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it probably can be.  This is your query:

```
SELECT d.dealerId
FROM `dealer_monthly_report` d 
WHERE d.dealerId <> 2 AND
      d.vin_prefix in (select distinct d2.vin_prefix
                       from `dealer_monthly_report` d2
                       where d2.dealerId = 2
                      ) 
GROUP BY d.dealerId;
```

I would re-write the query using `exists`:

```
SELECT d.dealerId
FROM `dealer_monthly_report` d 
WHERE d.dealerId <> 2 AND
      EXISTS (select 1
              from `dealer_monthly_report` d2
              where d2.dealerId = 2 and d.vin_prefix = d2.vin_prefix
             ) 
GROUP BY d.dealerId;
```

Then indexes on `dealer_monthly_report(dealerId)` and `dealer_monthly_report(vin_prefix, dealerId)` are best for performance.

If you have a table of dealers with the `vin_prefix`, then the best approach has no `group by` at all:

```
select dealerId d
from dealers d
where dealerid <> 2 and
      exists (select d2.vin_prefix
              from `dealer_monthly_report` dmr
              where d2.dealerId = 2 and dmr.vin_prefix = d.vin_prefix
             );
```

This would use an index on `dealer_monthly_report(vin_prefix, dealerId)` and `dealers(dealerid, vin_prefix)`.